# ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample`

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to read a csv file(2GB).Since the size is large I used dask but it is showing a ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`
Can anyone please suggest me how to slove it?
Thanks

Code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df= dd.read_csv('file1.csv')
```

error:

```
ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`
```

Answer (score 5):

The error means "please include the optional keyword argument `sample` in your call to `read_csv`, giving a value (in bytes) which is large enough to include one row of data". Looking at the function [docstring](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv), you'll see that the default value is 256000bytes.

So maybe try

```
df = dd.read_csv('file1.csv', sample=1000000)
```